# SQL: Filtering on a computed column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem that can't be that hard to solve, but I'm having problems with it.

A small table

```
create table tbl1
  ( a INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    b VARCHAR(100)
  );
```

and some data

```
insert into tbl1 
  (b) values
    ("/some/path/1"), 
    ("/some/path/2"), 
    ("/some/longer/path/1"),  
    ("/some/longer/path/2"),
    ("/some/way/1"),
    ("/some/longer/way/2");
```

The I want to query like this:

```
select length(b) - length(replace(b, '/', '')) no_dirs, b
  from tbl1
  where b like "%path%"
     and no_dirs = min(no_dirs);
```

which should return all rows where no_dirs has its miminum value. The last condition does not work.

I also fiddled with a subquery, but could not get that to work.

Suggestions?

Comment: you can't use alias names in `where` clauses. Replace the alias with the real calc value in your where clause and it should work

Comment: ^and all 3 current answers keep referring to no_dirs before it is defined......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to `no_dirs` in the `WHERE` clause because the `WHERE` is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause, so `no_dirs` does not exist yet.

Also you can't use `MIN` like that. This is a solution with a subquery:

```
SELECT length(b) - length(replace(b, '/', '')) no_dirs, b
FROM tbl1
WHERE b like "%path%"
  AND length(b) - length(replace(b, '/', '')) = (
                      SELECT MIN(length(b) - length(replace(b, '/', ''))) 
                      FROM tbl1
                      WHERE  b like "%path%" )
```

[See it working on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2a95c/10/0)

Comment: This assume you want the `MIN(no_dirs)` to be the minimum for paths that are `LIKE `%path%``. If actually you want it to be the minimum overall then remove that second `WHERE` - but I think you probably want it how I've posted.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks. Code looks a bit messy, but that's fine for now.

Comment: @user3048677 If I was you I'd be tempted to `SELECT` the `no_dirs` into a temporary table - it would look something like this ([SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a5b29/1/0)) except use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` instead of just `CREATE TABLE` (temporary tables don't work on SQLFiddle)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use the column alias or a grouped column in your where clause. therefore you use the calculation and a subselect

```
select length(b) - length(replace(b, '/', '')) no_dirs, b
  from tbl1
 where b like "%path%"
   and length(b) - length(replace(b, '/', '')) 
                             = (select min(no_dirs) from tbl1);
```